# How to use your own data in the selection box of azure pipeline plug-in

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-task

```js
    "dataSourceBindings": [
      {
        "target": "project",
        "endpointId": "$(FabrikamService)",
        "dataSourceName": "Fabfrikam Projects"
      }
    ]
```

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUySX.png)
How to use our own data for dynamically acquired data in a selection box

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, are you trying to select the your git repo for the
**Download GitHub Release** task.

> How to use your own data?

You can try setting your own data to the environment variable and refer to it in your pipeline tasks.

1,To [set a variable in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts), you can refer to below example

`- powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=repoName]variableValue"`

2,To set variables in the Pipeline edit UI page, you can click the Variables on the top right corner to add a variable.

[image]

3, Use `varibles` in yaml pipeline

`variables:
  repoName: variableValue
  configuration: debug
  platform: x64`

> Then you can refer to these variables in **Download GitHub Release** task like below example.

```
 - task: DownloadGitHubRelease@0
        inputs:
          connection: 'mygithubconnection'

          userRepository: '$(repoName)'

          defaultVersionType: 'latest'
          downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Please describe your question in details, if above doesnot answer your question.